# Generate Tree Diagram of Questions and Buttons in Xaml C#

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set up page in XAML and C# with a question and some buttons on it and then each of those buttons redirects to another page based on the user answer to the question - essentially a tree diagram of questions and answers that leads the user to a result. However I am not sure what is going to be the easiest way to do this.

Overall, the tree would contain approximately 60 Pages (nodes) with over 200 total buttons, a maximum of 4 buttons per page

My initial approach was to try and hard code each of these pages but this has proved too difficult and was wondering if anyone could suggest a way of doing this programmatically.

As an example (unrelated to the actual project). The first page might say "What is your gender" with the buttons "Male" and "Female", then if "Male" is clicked "Age?" with options ">18" and "<18" and go on asking more and more questions at deeper levels.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Answer** class with Properties:

- Text (of type `string`)
- NextQuestion (of type `Question`).

Create a **Question** class with Properties:

- Text (of type `string`)
- Answers (of type `List<Answer>`).

So that clicking an answer will hold the information as to what question to show next. This should give you a basic idea.